# Ручная блокировка таблицы в Oracle

Tags: oracle, php

Работаю с Oracle из PHP через OCI. Есть скрипт, который выполняет некоторые действия с таблицей. Одновременно могут работать 2 и более экземпляра этого скрипта, из-за этого действия над таблицей могут задваиваться. Пытаюсь избежать этого с помощью этого кода:

```
$r->query('LOCK TABLE t IN EXCLUSIVE MODE', array(), OCI_DEFAULT);
$r->query('SELECT id FROM t WHERE a = 1', array(), OCI_DEFAULT);
while ($r->fetch()) {
    $sql    = 'BEGIN UPDATE t SET a = 2 WHERE id = :p; END;';
    $params = array(
        array(
            ':p',
            $rs->result('ID')
        )
    );
    $r2->query($sql, $params, OCI_DEFAULT);
}
$rs->query('COMMIT');
```

Однако, данные как задваивались, так и задваиваються. Что не так с блокировкой? Ведь по идее Oracle не должен даже давать другим экземплярам скрипта читать из таблицы t, пока первый экземпляр не сделает commit.

Класс $r это просто обертка, которая делает ociparse потом oci_execute.

Answer (score 1):

А что вы хотите добится после выполения скрипта? Как я понял, вы сначала получаете из таблицы все ID, у которых a=1. Далее циклом проходите по результату и у каждого полученного ID делаете a=2. Если это так, то не проще все сделать одним запросом?

```
UPDATE t SET a = 2 WHERE a=1
```

и еще - что вы подразумеваете под задваиванием данных?

Comment: тут только концепция, на самом деле реальный код намного больше там вызываются еще функции, который делают что-то, по результатам чего отправляется почта. Бывает что приходит по 2 или больше писем

Comment: то есть под задваиванием вы понимаете именно отправку писем больше чем одного конкретному получателю?

Comment: Да. Одно письмо уходит пользователю больше одного раза. Происходит, на мой взгляд, следующее: первый экземпляр скрипта запускается и выбирает селектом все записи с a=1, начинает их обработку, в это время запускается другой экземпляр и выбирает те же самые записи, до того как первый успевает закомитить изменения, в результате данные обрабатываются два раза, чего хотелось бы избежать

Comment: Разобрался в чем было дело -  в дебрях кода затесался лишний commit. Убрал его и все заработало как ожидалось.